# Stop Photoshop from automatically resizing images that are dragged and dropped into a image that is being worked on

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixels

When I drag and drop an image file into an image I am working on, Photoshop automatically resizes the image (presumably based on canvas size?).

To give a specific example: I am creating a sprite sheet with a size of 240x240 (a  5x5 sheet of 48x48 sprites) and drag a 48x48 PNG file into it, the pasted gets resized (in this case by a factor of 2.5 to a size of 120x120). For now I can just drag the pasted object back to its original size. It's still a major annoyance and hurts productivity.

The solution I came across was disabling “Resize Image During Place” and “Always Create Smart Objects when placing,” but neither of them had any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To give a specific example: I am creating a sprite sheet with a size of 240x240 (a 5x5 sheet of 48x48 sprites) and drag a 48x48 PNG file into it, the pasted gets resized (in this case by a factor of 2.5 to a size of 120x120).

This all sounds weird, but also very familiar. To me, this sounds like some kinda of DPI mismatch between images.

Meaning the images you are attempting to drag into the Photoshop workspace window might be a higher DPI than the actual Photoshop workspace.

I would recommend you change the DPI of the images so they match each other on some level; either one image gets a higher DPI or the other gets a lower DPI but they should both be at the same DPI and then trying to drag and drop them again.